Threadpool latency is very high in single-cpu machine?
I am using a thread pool to execute task in parallel.
here is the code i use:
pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>

class ThreadPool {
public:
  ThreadPool(size_t threads) : stop(false) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
      workers.emplace_back(  // thread variable, emplace back just pass in a function for thread to construct
        [this] {
          for(;;) {
            std::function<void()> task;
            {   
              std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queue_mutex);
              this->condition.wait(lock, [this] { return this->stop || !this->tasks.empty(); }); 
              if(this->stop && this->tasks.empty()) return;  // only on stop and empty task, perfect exit
              task = std::move(this->tasks.front());  // get the first task
              this->tasks.pop();
            }   
            task();
          }   
        }); 
  }


  template<class F, class... Args>
  auto enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type> {
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;
    auto task = std::make_shared< std::packaged_task<return_type()> >(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    std::future<return_type> res = task->get_future();
    {   
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
      // don't allow enqueueing after stopping the pool
      if(stop) throw std::runtime_error("enqueue on stopped ThreadPool");
      tasks.emplace([task](){ (*task)(); }); 
    }   
    condition.notify_one();
    return res;
  }

  ~ThreadPool() {
    {   
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
      stop = true;
    }   
    condition.notify_all();
    for(std::thread &worker: workers) worker.join();
  }
private:
    std::vector< std::thread > workers;
    std::queue< std::function<void()> > tasks;
    std::mutex queue_mutex;
    std::condition_variable condition;
    bool stop;
};



the main.cpp is:
#include "./thread_pool.hpp"
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {
  ThreadPool tp(16);
  timeval t;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    tp.enqueue([t, i]() {
      timeval t1; 
      gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
      int lat = (t1.tv_sec - t.tv_sec) * 1000000 + t1.tv_usec - t.tv_usec;
      printf("this is loop %zu, lat = %d\n", i, lat);
    }); 
  }
}

i am testing the latency of this code (overhead latency).
the result suprised me.
in my 16-cpu i9 10900k machine, the latency only about 30us for each task.
in my 2-cpu aws machine, the latency will reach > 10000us.
I know the 2-cpu with 16 thread is not real paralla, but i think it will only slow down from 30-50us
to 10000us is much bigger than my expection, where is the time-costly part?

have the same number of thread workers as the number of virtual cores you have.

thanks, i tried reduce the thread size, the latency is still high (>1ms), just want to know why

Not owning the machine definitely contributes, this is running with virtualization on a machine where other workloads are running, the OS may take a while to allocate a core for you

@AhmedAEK so, the aws server is busy with task, it delays me 10ms to allocate cpu for me to execute task?

Unless someone that works at AWS can confirm we can only speculate, you should probably be checking the throughput instead or average the latency over a long number of requests taking into account those occasional spikes, there are dedicated tests for that (p99), your simple code doesn't really produce any useful information

are you using the same OS on each machine?

When a thread runs on a core, the OS scheduler as no reason to stop it except in few cases. More specifically, a thread is executed on the target core until the scheduling quantum ends unless the thread wait (passively) for some external operations before (e.g. lock, IO, etc.) and unless another ready thread has a higher priority. The time of the quantum on most mainstream machine is about 8-10 ms AFAIK. It match with the observed time. When no core are available, ready threads are pending until one becomes available.

in my 16-cpu i9 10900k machine, the latency only about 30us for each task.

If cores are available, then a ready thread can start directly, hence a low latency.

I know the 2-cpu with 16 thread is not real paralla, but i think it will only slow down from 30-50us

The scheduling quantum is the source of the much higher latency in this case. It cannot be too small because context switches are expensive on mainstream machines (typically in the order of microseconds if not even dozens of microseconds due to the quite recent security patches). As a result, a quantum of 30-50 µs is nearly impossible to have without a huge overhead. Note the quantum time is dependent of the target platform (mainly the OS and the architecture).
If you want such a low overhead, then you can use software user threads and a user-defined cooperative scheduling. If you care about latency, then the number of ready thread should never be higher than the number of core. Tuning the latency of the target thread pool can also help to reduce the latency of more critical operations.
